# Why is creating ArrayList with initial capacity slow?

Tags: java, arraylist

Comparing creating large ArrayList with intialCapacity I found that it;s slower than creting it without one. Here is the simple program I wrote to measure it:

```
long start2 = System.nanoTime();
List<Double> col = new ArrayList<>(30000000); // <--- Here
for (int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++) {
    col.add(Math.sqrt(i + 1));
}
long end2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(end2 - start2);
System.out.println(col.get(12411325).hashCode() == System.nanoTime());
```

The average result for new `ArrayList<>(30000000)`: `6121173329`

The average result for new `ArrayList<>()`: `4883894100`

on my machine. I thought that it would be faster to create large array once rather than reacreating it once we go beyond the capacity of the current underlying array of `ArrayList`. Eventually we should have ended up with array size greater or equal than `30000000`.

I thought it was optimization, but actualy pessimization. Why that?

Comment: @ManoDestra So, what is the purpose of the initial capacity, when to use it?

Comment: When you add the `30,000,000`th element, the `List` expands to `60,000,000` elements. Try increasing the initial capacity by `1` (but do not add another number to the `List`).

Comment: @ManoDestra How comes to is "Way to high", if it is _exactly_ the size of the List after the `for` lopp? I would surprise me if the OPs findings are actually true, because without the initial capacity set, the ArrayList will have to reallocate and copy itself for `ceil(log2(30000000/10)) = 22` times and in the end have a internal capacity of `41943040`, more than 30% too much.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you can dig up the source code where that is written, this will be an excellent answer!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch are you sure? I just tested your suggestion and got the same results: the 2nd variation took only 2/3 of the time. However when I use `Integer` and do a `col.add(i);`, then the first variation is slightly faster!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Have tried it, and the result was almost the same.

Comment: How are you actually timing this? Just once? Averaged over multiple runs? Different order?  Ramp-up time?

Comment: @copeg I ran the same program multiple times. It was not in a loop.

Comment: If I run this averaged over multiple runs together with an initial ramp-up time setting the initial capacity is faster time and again

Comment: All sources I could find claim that the capacity is only increased when adding an element would lead to an overflow and not before. About the size I read it's <old_capacity> * 3 / 2 + 1 and not double exactly, but it's not specified in the API.

Comment: if you're doing a small benchmark, I suggest reading through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: If you think about it, the capacity can't be doubled, because an initial capacity of 0 is allowed. Therefore I think the given formula is probably correct, although the API only states that the default initial capacity is 10 and says nothing about the growth of the ArrayList.

Comment: @maraca Thanks. Left brain at home this morning :D

Answer (score 6):

> I ran the same program multiple times. It was not in a loop

Consider how you are profiling the code - if you include both a *'ramp up time'* (to take into account things such as *JIT*) and *average over several* calls (to gather some statistics/distribution), the timing may lead you to a different conclusion. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Warm up
    System.out.println("Warm up");
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
        dynamic();
        constant();
    }
    System.out.println("Timing...");
    //time
    long e = 0;
    long s = 0; 
    int total = 5;
    for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ){
        long e1 = dynamic();
        System.out.print(e1 + "\t");
        e += e1;
        long s1 = constant();
        System.out.println(s1);
        s += s1;
    }
    System.out.println("Static Avg: " + (s/total));
    System.out.println("Dynamic Avg: " + (e/total));

}

private static long dynamic(){
    long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Double> col = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++) {
        col.add(Math.sqrt(i + 1));
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return end2 - start2;
}

private static long constant(){
    long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Double> col = new ArrayList<>(30000000); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++) {
        col.add(Math.sqrt(i + 1));
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return end2 - start2;
}
```

On my system setting the initial capacity is always faster, though not by any orders of magnitude.

Edit: As suggested in a comment, consider reading through [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: My results: Static Avg: 7544; Dynamic Avg: 2379 !?

Comment: Consider a) not just the mean but the distribution b) the rules in the link in edit (my code doesn't necessarily abide by all of them)